# Typescript error when using generator function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to resolve the typescript error when using generator function?

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Will take care in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the return type yourself:

```
function* flatten(array: string[], depth: number): Generator<string, void, void> {
   ...
}
```

`Generator` is a generic type declared as `Generator<T, TReturn, TNext>`, where `T` stands for type of value spitted out of generator on `yield`, `TReturn` stands for type of value which generator returns with `return` statement and `TNext` stands for type of value which `generator.next(value: TNext)` accepts.

Your generator function spits out strings, returns nothing and never uses values which generator accepts via `next` – therefore it's type should be `Generator<string, void, void>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake and giving explanation also.